# hide next button in bootstrap modal carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, blueimp

I use this

https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery

for bootstrap carousel in bootstrap modal. This works perfectly. But I need to hide, the previous button, if I am on the first slide and hide the next button, if I am on the last slide Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, disable continuous

```
var options = {
//Allow continuous navigation, moving from last to first
// and from first to last slide:

continuous: false,
};

or make

continuous: !1  // In jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js
```

Second, add id's on next and previous buttons

```
<button id="prv" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
     Previous
</button>
<button id="nxt" type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
     Next
</button>
```

Third, add CSS for id's

```
.blueimp-gallery-left #prv, .blueimp-gallery-right #nxt{
display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Events Callback function from the documentation. You can hide the previous and next button in base of a few functions ([documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md))

```
var gallery = blueimp.Gallery(
    linkList,
    {
        onopened: function () {
            // Callback function executed when the Gallery has been initialized
            // and the initialization transition has been completed.
        },
        onslidecomplete: function (index, slide) {
            // Callback function executed on slide content load.
        },

    }
);
```

Or try to set on the var options `carousel: false`

Comment: Thanks. My JS knowledge is weak, my I know how to do this.

Comment: Try the second way first since it is easier. You just have to include it on the `var option` of JS. It has to be somewhere in your code when you run the script.

Comment: I tried giving `carousel:false` but prev/next button still visible for first/last slide